# What's the means of error code 0xc0220002 in Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: wfp

When I use `FwpmFilterAdd()` function,it return code `0xc0220002`.What's that means?

Comment: http://www.microsoftfixit.eu/fix-0xc0220002/

Answer (score 1):

When calling kernel mode WFP API, they return NTSTATUS, instead of Win32 error code. This is important, because MSDN docs list out only Win32 error codes, which is fine if you are calling them in user mode, but would be incorrect for the same APIs in kernel mode.

Here is your NTSTATUS, taken from [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx):

```
0xC0220002
STATUS_FWP_CONDITION_NOT_FOUND
The filter condition does not exist.
```